# javascript for jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to use a Jinja template to consume data to populate a webpage.

The code is:
"

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-info collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#title">Programme Title</button>
  <div id="title" class="collapse">
    <!-- START of TABLE  -->    


    <table>
        <thead>
            <th> Programme Title </th>
            <th class="midc"> Lead (s) </th>
            <th class="midc"> Theme </th>
            <th class="midc"> Cluster </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for p in progs %}
            <tr>
            <td><a href="programmes/{{ p.programme_ID }}"><mark>{{ p.Programme }}</mark></a> </td>
            {% endfor %}                    
            <td>
            {% for pc in pclus %}
            <label for="content"> Lead(s) </label>
            <select name="staffroles">
                    <option value=Null></option>
                    {% if pc.cluster_ID == pclus % }                        
                        <option value={{ p.cluster_ID }} selected> {{ p.Name }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                        <option value={{ pc.cluster_ID }}> {{ p.Name }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td class="midc"> {{ p.cluster_id }} </td>
            </tr>                                   
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </tbody>

    </table>


    </div>
    <!-- END OF TABLE -->
</div>
```

The second block "{% for pc in pclus %}" is for a drop-down list.

I had a block of code commented out. I removed the commented out code.

I got a new error message.

Error message:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}'

Comment: I think it would help to see more of your template. I believe you have one too many `{% endfor %}`-tags somewhere

Comment: I had some code blocked out using <!-- --> within the block this was throwing the inner block error.

Comment: So is this solved then?

Comment: No. I got a new error.

Comment: Hi Pax. Thanks for your input. I updated the code adding the entire block. The second {% for pc in pclus %} is for a drop-down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line `{% if pc.cluster_ID == pclus % }`, there is an extra space at the end right before the `}`, which makes jinja think that `if pc.cluster_ID == pclus %` is a complete python statement. Remove the space and the error should be gone.